# How to use .$watch to get the updated json array length from firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a code that get json array data from firebase...

```
var ref = new Firebase("firebase object path");
  var sync = $firebase(ref);


  $firebaseArray(ref).$loaded().then(function(data){
    console.log(data.length)//here i get the length
  });
```

From the above code i get the array length but when o delete a value from the firebase database the length is not updated... but to do that i dont know how to use .$watch ... can anyone help me how to integerate .$watch in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to use $watch. He will be greatly slow down Your website. Use the construction with "on":

```
ref.on('child_added', function(data){                   
    console.log(ref.length);
             });   
ref.on('child_changed', function(data){
     console.log(ref.length);               
             });
```

Try something like this (I have not tested this)

Comment: Thnks for the replay... I have tried the code you sent me .. but i didn't get response from the console